# How to develop my first app for Mac?

Tags: ios, macos

Now am working for iPhone/iPad applications. Am interesting to develop apps for Mac OS X also. I searched some tutorials for developing app for Mac in Google and i need to learn something about Mac apps. Can anyone please suggest me any tutorials, links, blocks to create a simple mac apps? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is such a vague question, it might appear that you haven't even researched much. you have provided no direction other than "i need to develop an app". I would say that google search is still your friend and you need to spend more time with it so you can come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Silvertiger. I will use Google. But, i searched my level best in Google before asking this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use apple documentation for mac os library in your xcode..It is the best way to learn developing applications for mac... http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code

Answer (score 0):

Go through the tutorials at [Cocoa Dev Central](http://cocoadevcentral.com/) and you'll be up to speed in no time.